# Xcode 10+: how to switch to legacy build system?

Tags: xcode, xcode11, xcode10, xcode12, legacy-build-system

There seem to be some [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50552752/45813) with the new build system in Xcode 10. How do I switch to the old (legacy) build system?

---

**NOTE:** While one can apparently still use it for a bit longer (in June 2022), the legacy build system is marked deprecated in Xcode 13.4.1)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can switch back to the previous (legacy) build system from the menu by 
`File > Workspace Settings...` (or `Project Settings...`):

[image: menu]

This brings up a dialog where you can change the `Build System` to `Legacy Build System`:

[image]

Hat tip to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52657077/45813). There's also a video [here](https://medium.com/xcblog/five-things-you-must-know-about-xcode-10-new-build-system-41676cd5fd6c).

Comment: Yes, but this wont work if you are using Swift Packages in your project.