# CocoaPods: Multiple commands produce

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

```
Showing Recent Messages
:-1: Multiple commands produce '/Users/coel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXX-ercdvkscrqvgfqhfocqthkuzinrp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/XXXXXXXXXXX/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/CocoaLumberjack.framework':
1) Target 'CocoaLumberjack-Default-Swift' has create directory command with output '/Users/coel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXX-ercdvkscrqvgfqhfocqthkuzinrp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/XXXXXXXX/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/CocoaLumberjack.framework'
2) Target 'CocoaLumberjack.default-Swift' has create directory command with output '/Users/coel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXXXX-ercdvkscrqvgfqhfocqthkuzinrp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/XXXXXXXXX/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/CocoaLumberjack.framework'
```

[image]

If I remove one of them,then the header file can't be found.I can be debug but can not be archived.

Comment: Using the old build system is likely a workaround

Comment: Sorry,But I don't want to switch to a lower Xcode

Comment: not necessary - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53050109/556617

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recording the answer discussed in the comments:

Using the old Xcode build system is a workaround. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53050109/556617).

Answer (score 3):

I encounter this problem when I have multiple targets.

Please make sure that your targets have the same IOS Version under `General -> Deployment Info` and run pod install again.[image]