# xcodebuild gives signing error when it shouldn't

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

I execute the following `xcodebuild` command line:

```
xcodebuild CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO 
 -workspace "MyThing.xcworkspace" -scheme "MyScheme" 
 -configuration 'Debug' -sdk iphoneos clean build
```

and get this error:

```
error: An empty identity is not valid when signing a binary
 for the product type 'Application'. (in target 'MyTarget')
```

This used to work. How can I fix it?

This is using Xcode 10.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason, this seems to be (yet another) strange side effect of using Xcode's new build system. You can fix this from the `xcodebuild` command line by forcing use of the legacy build system, using the following flag:

```
-UseModernBuildSystem=0
```

To set up your project/workspace to use the legacy build system for everything, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53050109/45813).

---

**NOTE:** While one can apparently still use it for a bit longer (in June 2022), the legacy build system is marked deprecated in Xcode 13.4.1)

Comment: I had to resort to this fix, but it did sort the issue out. No idea why. Gotta love Apple's ecosystem..