# "Use of undeclared identifier '__BYTE_ORDER' " error after updating pod

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

Getting these two errors, after updating pods:

`Use of undeclared identifier '__BYTE_ORDER'`
`Use of undeclared identifier '__LITTLE_ENDIAN'`

**Using Xcode Version 11.2.1 (11B53)**

[image: Xcode errors]

Comment: Have you tried switching to *Legacy Build System* as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58546774/211765)?

Comment: @Tom, Thanks for your reply. I have solved it, check out my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I have solved my problem. I have done the following steps:

**1) Uninstall pod:**
To remove pods from a project completely you need to install two things.

a) Cocoapods-Deintegrate Plugin
b) Cocoapods-Clean Plugin

To install those, open your terminal and type

```
sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate
```

*(Press enter)*

```
sudo gem install cocoapods-clean
```

Now go to your project directory by typing this on your terminal

```
cd (path of the project) //Remove the braces after cd
```

Then press enter and type

```
pod deintegrate
```

to deintegrate pod. Then type

```
pod cache clean --all
```

to clean the cache. Now type

```
pod clean
```

to clean pod directory.

After completing the above tasks there should be the Podfile still remaining on your project directory. Just delete that manually or use this following command on the terminal.

```
rm Podfile
```

Then delete the DerivedData from Xcode by typing

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

Or follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49118434/2435154) to delete it manually.

Now remove Cocoapods from the system

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

That's it. Now you have your project free from Pods & Cleaned.

**2) Install pod:**
After that, install a fresh pod to your project by following:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

For MacOS, Catalina

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 1.8.4
```

Latest CocoaPods 1.10.0 seem not working. More info is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66444509/2435154). Then give your project path

```
cd /your project path
```

Now type

```
pod setup
```

Init the Pod

```
pod init
```

Open Pod file and add Pod list into it
For example

```
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
```

Then install those pods.

```
pod install
```

Now `open your-project.xcworkspace`. The errors should be gone.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A clean installation of Firebase pods worked for me:

1) Comment out or temporarily remove all Firebase related pods from the Podfile

2) Update pods - this will remove all previously installed pods - run:

```
pod update
```

3) Uncomment or add back the Firebase related pods and run 'pod update' to install them.